# Relationship of a Post model to both city and country (from Location model)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `Post` model and a `Location` model. I have setup the many-to-many relationship so that `$post->getCities` and `$location->getPosts` work by introducing an intermediate table. This is the Locations table:

[image]

Now, what I want to do is to get all the posts that belong to a country? Is this possible with the existing tables and relationships that I have?

Comment: You mean [Querying relationship existance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)  ?

Answer (score 0):

If your `$post->getCities` looks something like that

```
return $this->hasMany(Location::class, ...);
```

Then QueryBuilder is returned, allowing you to filter your query in a casual way before executing request to the database:

```
$post->getCities()->where('country', $yourCountry)->get();
```

Otherwise, if your `$post->getCities` already returns a collection, you can apply [where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-where) method on the collection and filter it on the side of your application:

```
$locations = $post->getCities(...);
$locationsByCountry = $locations->where('country', $youtCountry);
```

Comment: please take note that a post can belong to NY but not to LA.